# iOS: ASIHTTPRequest POST not working whereas GET works with exactly same URL

Tags: ios

I have used ASIHTTPRequest API in my code. The GET request is successful but the POST request is not working. The only difference is, I have appended post data encoded with NSUTF8Encoding in case of POST request. The POST API works in case of Android app. 
Following is my code:

```
NSString *strToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"access_token=\"%@\"", securityToken];

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request addRequestHeader:@"ContentType" value:@"application/json"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:strToken];

if( type == GET )
    [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
else if( type == POST )
{
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request appendPostData:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
}
else if( type == PUT )
{
    [request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];
    [request appendPostData:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
}

[request setDelegate:owner];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo in the request header key 'ContentType'. The expected key was 'Content-Type'.